# Kafka Connector is getting time out when opening in connect-distributed mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

kafka-connect is getting error as below when opening in distributor mode. I've already increased the some connect-distributed.propertieses parameters which as below. I have to open connect in distributed mode also.

connect-distributed.properties;

```
offset.flush.interval.ms=5000
offset.flush.timeout.ms=300000
producer.buffer.memory=300097152
status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

---

```
INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-8] Disconnecting from node 0 due to request timeout. 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:797)
INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-8] Cancelled in-flight METADATA request with 
correlation id 530256 due to node 0 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 1ms, 
elapsed time since send: 1ms, request timeout: 0ms) 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:341)
WARN Attempt 2 to list offsets for topic partitions resulted in RetriableException; retrying 
automatically. Reason: Timed out while waiting to get end offsets for topic 'connect-offsets' 
on brokers at *.*.*.*:9092 (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.RetryUtil:84)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out while waiting to get end offsets 
for topic 'connect-offsets' on brokers at *.*.*.*:9092
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=metadata, 
deadlineMs=1680677446792, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1680677446893) timed out at 1680677446793 
after 1 attempt(s)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.TopicAdmin.endOffsets(TopicAdmin.java:672)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.TopicAdmin.lambda$retryEndOffsets$6(TopicAdmin.java:725)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.RetryUtil.retryUntilTimeout(RetryUtil.java:82)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.TopicAdmin.retryEndOffsets(TopicAdmin.java:724)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog.readEndOffsets(KafkaBasedLog.java:375)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog.readToLogEnd(KafkaBasedLog.java:335)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog.start(KafkaBasedLog.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore.start(KafkaOffsetBackingStore.java:151)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.start(Worker.java:186)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.startServices(AbstractHerder.java:135)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:320)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=metadata, 
    deadlineMs=1680677446792, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1680677446893) timed out at 
    1680677446793 after 1 attempt(s)
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: Cancelled metadata request 
    with correlation id 530256 due to node 0 being disconnected
```

I've also added the  result of the connect-offsets detail.

```
kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 -describe --topic connect-offsets
Topic: connect-offsets  TopicId: naW7oTihQwK PartitionCount: 25      
ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: 
cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=1073741824
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 2    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 3    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 4    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 5    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 6    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 7    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 8    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 9    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 10   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 11   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 12   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 13   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 14   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 15   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 16   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 17   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 18   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 19   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 20   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 21   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 22   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 23   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
Topic: connect-offsets  Partition: 24   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
```

Comment: Well, is Kafka running at `*.*.*.*:9092`? Can you use `kafka-topics --describe --topic connect-offsets` for that cluster?

Comment: I added the result to the question.

Comment: In your original post, you had `*.*.*.*:9092`. Not localhost... Are you sure you're using the correct bootstrap address?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure I'm using localhost, I just kept it for security.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. The topic clearly exists. You could try increasing AdminClient timeout properties in your properties file. Or you can use `connect-standalone` on a single machine

Comment: Actually That problem happened after broker shut down and zookeeper didn't return from last snap because I had changed datadir path which ı lost old one of zookeeper and then connect-distributor haven't started yet anymore with that above error. I started connect in connect-standalone mode but it doesn't convenience way to use connector. You know if the connect-standalone restarted, the all of connectors which are already running before restart are lost.

Comment: You need to use multiple args for Standalone.  `connect-standalone connect-standalone.properties connector-1.properties connector-2.properties ...`

Comment: In one hand Our connectors could be changeable such as delete or create new one on the other hand we don't want to lose our old connectors when connect stopped. İs it possible to do that with connect-standalone mode? By the way I really appreciated for your attention.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "lose". [Connect standalone writes metadata to disk](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/concepts.html#workers), so as long as you use the same machine, nothing should be "lost". You would stop the process to remove/update connectors, or run a new `connect-standalone` job to start new ones. But, this was just my suggestion for a workaround. Distributed mode is definitely recommended to run at scale. Regardless, your error doesn't make sense to me because the topic clearly exists. I simply think you've shown two different `bootstrap.servers` here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue has been solved when I delete all of files which were kafka log.dirs and zookeeper data files.